# Get Ansible Localhost Ipv4.address

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get ipv4 address of localhost, 
Tried to tested before I use it as a variable is my j2 template

```
ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_default_ipv4.address'
```

Output of this command is

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {},
    "changed": false
}
```

So it is empty.
Why? Is it some bug?

Answer (score 0):

A fact (the value to use in the `filter` argument) is `ansible_default_ipv4`. It is a dictionary and contains a key `address`.

There is no way to filter on values, so you need to use:

```
ansible localhost -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_default_ipv4'
```

Comment: I found the problem! It's working when you trying to use againts remote host but not for localhost

Answer (score 0):

Try this adhoc ansible setup module filter for me it's working.

```
$ ansible dev -m setup -a 'filter=ansible_all_ipv4_addresses'

node1.example.com | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "10.160.12.13"
        ],
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false
}
```